# Ad-hoc OTA distribution install error

Tags: iphone, ios, distribution, ad-hoc-distribution, over-the-air

I have created an ad-hoc distribution ipa file along with a plist file and uploaded it onto a website. I have then navigated to the website and clicked the download link. It pops up saying:

> www.mywebsite.co.uk would like to install "myApp"

So I click install.

It then reverts to the home screen to show the icon and the progress bar of the download/install.

Once the bar has reached c.3/4 it then shows another pop up saying:

> Unable to download application
>
> "My App" could not be installed at this time.

Any thoughts on what is going wrong here?

Comment: you have to check your provision profile or destination file path folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness..

I had migrated my project from one laptop to another during the build and had forgotten about it. I had therefore migrated all my profiles but not my private and public shared keys in keychain. Ultimately. I have to delete all certificates and profiles and start again from Keychain.

Actually, once I have decided to start all over again, it was probably only 15 mins to a full distribution profile working. Not bad considering the number hours scratching my head beforehand. But still - Apple...surely you can think of a more slick way of allowing us to test and distribute apps?????